# Why I am getting "variable has incomplete type 'llvm::StringRef'"?

Tags: c++, llvm

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>

#include "llvm/Support/DynamicLibrary.h"

int my_add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}

int main() {
    const char *name = "my_add";
    llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::AddSymbol("my_add", (void*)&my_add);

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with

```
g++ `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs all` A.cpp -g -o A
```

I am getting an error here:

A.cpp:11:42: error: argument type 'llvm::StringRef' is incomplete
    llvm::sys::DynamicLibrary::AddSymbol("my_add", (void*)&my_add);

How to fix this problem?

Comment: `#include <llvm/ADT/StringRef.h>`?